# How to send form data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to build a small website. I have backend almost done but i can't find how can i send form data to server. Here is my attempt and i want to send the data to localhost running at port 3000 for example:

```
jQuery('#signUp-Form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Sending data');
    var name = jQuery('[name = username]').val();
//    socket.emit('sign-up',{
//      username: jQuery('[name = username]').val(),
//      password: jQuery('[name = password]').val()
//    });
});
```

I can do with socket.io but however i want to use `POST,GET etc` and at server side i built my server with express.

I can retrieve the name from the field into the `var name` and now i want to send it to server: here is the function which will handle this request. Only first two lines:

```
app.post('/login',(req,res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['username', 'password']);
```

Now my question is how can i send data in such format so that '/login' matches with pattern and `req.body` contains the name only.

It is the basic question but i don't see anywhere how can i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khan, it looks like you are attempting two methods of form submission: non-AJAX and AJAX. From your question it's not apparent which method is intended, but I will show both methods:

#### Non-AJAX

Using `<form action="/login" method="POST">`:

```html
<form id="myform" action="/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

This method will refresh the page and make a POST request to /login sending the [url encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) data like:

```
username=nha&password=asonteu
```

#### AJAX

With AJAX, *the page won't refresh*, and you must send the data programmatically:

```
$( "#myform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = $( this ).serialize();
    //make our request here
    $.post( "/login", function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

`serialize()` also url encodes the form data.

Your server *must* handle any expected data format (to extract the fields properly). URL encoding is useful, but later you will see [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or perhaps [protobufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers). It really doesn't matter which format you use as long as both the client and server agree.

*NOTE: With POST, the data will be in the request body*

I hope this helps!

Comment: The second one is what i was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @KhanSaab Awesome, glad I could help!